# What is the best way in Java to parse semantic data from a source?

Tags: java, semantic-markup, semantic-analysis

I would like to read and parse a marked up text (probably microformat, microdata, rdf or similar). Do I have create my own parser or is there any java library which can help with this?

Comment: Here is a good post about your question, it has several libraries listed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73445/what-are-some-good-java-rdf-libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you already googled from this?! :-) "microformat +java parser" on Google will give you a link to http://microformats.org/wiki/parsers

Comment: Actually, this is the first result googling "microdata java"

Answer (score 0):

Microformats are microdata are, although with a shared goal, different technologies.

I'd recommend you to take a look to [Apache Any23](https://any23.apache.org)